# Converting mkv to mp4 vs ogv vs webm

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, webm, mkv

I am trying to convert an mkv file to mp4, webm, and ogv using ffmpeg and I am getting really drastic performance results.

The mkv -> mp4 conversion took all of 2 seconds while the webm and ogv conversions took about 5-10minutes. Is there a faster way to convert to these formats?

Commands used:

mkv -> mp4

```
ffmpeg -i ironman2trailer.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -absf aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

mkv -> webm

```
ffmpeg -i -f webm -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis output.webm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second command the most of the time was probably taken by video encoding.

More specifically, in addition to changing file container format (that is from `mkv` to `webm`), the second command changed codecs of video and audio streams. This includes decoding original streams and encoding them with new codecs.

Your first command just changed the file container format that is not a processor-intensive operation. The original audio and video streams encodings were kept intact that is specified by `copy` option for audio and video codecs.

Comment: thank you. that helps clear things up. however is there a way to convert to webm and ogv faster using something else from php?

Comment: You would need to do codec-specific fine-tuning. I do not know much about `webm` but [WebM web video encoding tutorial with FFMpeg](https://www.virag.si/2012/01/webm-web-video-encoding-tutorial-with-ffmpeg-0-9/) appears to provide a good description. I have not tried it though and cannot tell how complete or accurate it is.